# express-session won't apply cookie setting

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

I use session with mongo store, but the problem is that cookie setting won't get change :

```js
app.use(
  session({
    name: 'session',
    store: store,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || '',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'none' },
  })
)
```

no matter what the cookie setting is, it always use the default one.

Actually when i change the options , cookie option to the database will be save correctly, but cookie will be send with the default options!

I delete the database session collection, used postman, nothing worked.
I set cookie manually for authentication with the same configuration and it works fine but on express-session not.